# Swift - Can a class conform some protocol programmatically?

Tags: swift, protocols, anonymous-class

I have a function that receives a variable and I want that variable to conforms some protocol, but I don't know the class that is coming and I don't want to make that class to implements the protocol directly in the class file or using an extension, I want to somehow hide it

It's that possible?

Comment: This is not possible. What do you mean by dynamically conforming?

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought it wasn't possible but I decided to ask anyway, 

I mean if I can received a parameter in a function and makes it to conform some protocol, that's what I meant with "programmatically"